# Error on getting aws account root user details using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

I am trying to get the root user details in an AWS account in lambda function using boto3, however it gives the below error.

```
"errorMessage": "An error occurred (NoSuchEntity) when calling the GetUser operation: The user with name root cannot be found.",
"errorType": "NoSuchEntityException"
```

Code Snippet:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('iam')
response = client.get_user(
UserName='root'
)
```

Comment: Why do you wish to retrieve information about the root user in a Lambda function? This is a very unusual requirement.

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein,
Thanks for answering. The requirement here is to automatically disable root users access and secret key (make it inactive). I am trying to create a custom AWS config rule , which checks for the access key usage for the root user and if it's active , then make it inactive using a lambda function. However, I have been unable to find a way to get the details of the root user so far. IAM user details works fine. Do you have any suggestions around it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no IAM user called *root*.

The *root* user is actually associated with the AWS Account. It is totally separate to IAM, which allows individuals users to be created.

You cannot *disable* the Access Key associated with the root user, but you can [Delete Access Keys from the Root User](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_root-user.html#id_root-user_manage_delete-key).

The [delete-access-key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/delete-access-key.html) documentation isn't too clear, but it does make reference to being able to delete the keys via an API call. If I'm reading it correctly, **the root keys can be deleted — but only calling the function as the *root* user**. This would not be possible from a Lambda function.

The best course of action is probably to **delete the *root* key via the management console**, then try to find a way to monitor it (but I suspect there is no call that could provide this information). Fortunately, the credentials can only be added back by logging into the console as the *root* user. Adding an **MFA token** would limit the likelihood of this happening.